# npm link <package> issue

Tags: angular, npm

> Windows 7, 64-bit
>   Npm 3.10.10
>   Node 6.9.4

Hi,

We are currently working with a custom npm package (published on our registry and installed in our Angular applications) and it causes some troubles.

See below the different scenarios that we have tested :

**Build the package, publish it on our registry then install it in our applications**

`npm run build
npm publish dist --registry http://registry.com
cd /path/to/angular-application
npm install package-name
npm start`

=> WORKS

**Build the package, link it, use it in our applications**

`npm run build
cd dist
npm link
cd /path/to/angular-application
npm link package-name
npm start`

=> DOES NOT WORK (no specific error message)

**Build the package, copy the /dist folder, paste the /dist folder in our applications (in the /package-name directory)**

=> WORKS

**Build the package, link it, copy the global /package-name folder created with the npm link command, paste it in our applications (in the /package-name directory)**

=> WORKS

We arrived to the conclusion that the problem is not with the npm link command itself, but with the use of this link in our applications : the /dist folder is correctly created and the files are working in our applications if we use them through a copy/paste.

Any idea of what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should write npm link in the same directory with your package.json, not in dist.